# No window popup when including 2 jquery files in code

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

In my page, the jquery.min.js 1.9.1 file is necessary to show a popup window. But in my page, I have a navigation bar that works using the jquery.min.js 1.8.1.

Now both of these files are having a conflict and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Remove the one from Kendo. Use latest version of jQuery.

Comment: then the window is not opening :/

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery.noConflict, you can make multiple versions of jQuery coexist on the same page.  For instance

```
<script src='jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script>
var jq132 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src='jquery-1.8.1.js'></script>
<script>
var jq142 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [jQuery.migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) (after the reference to jQuery 1.9.1).

Some javascript components require futures that have removed in jQuery 1.9. jQuery.migrate solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var k=jQuery.noConflict();
```

replace the $ with k in the new JS you are writing like this

if you have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#selector').click(function(){
      alert('Hi');
 });
});
```

it should be written like

```
j(document).ready(function(){
 j('#selector').click(function(){
      alert('Hi');
 });
});
```

after using the noConflict..